# "Unable to initialize device" sending print command to shared printer

Tags: windows, command-line, printing, hostname

From a Windows 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 Server I have a problem sending a print command to a network host running Windows 7 Professional which shares a printer with the network. The command I execute is the following:

```
> print /D:\\<hostname>\<printer_sharename> <filename>
```

and it doesn't work. The response is:

```
Unable to initialize device \\<hostname>\<printer_sharname>
```

If I try to execute the following command

```
> print /D:\\<host'sipaddress>\<printer_sharename> <filename>
```

from the Windows Server it works.

If I execute the command with the hostname from any other machine in the network it works.

I thought it could be a DNS problem, so I tried to check hostname with nslookup but it works, DNS server give me the right IP address.

I would use hostname instead of IP address because Microsoft Reference say to use \\ServerName\PrinterName https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731623.aspx

Why I'm having this behavior? Any ideas?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: How am I supposed to guess I need a backslash before the device's name (i.e. after /d:)??? 
Other sources:   
https://ss64.com/nt/print.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/print

None are clear about this. Btw, I tried adding that backslash, but I got a blank extensionless file. Also, when trying running the ```print``` command again, I get the same ```Unable to start device``` thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the problem, there were many other problems connected to the hostname of that windows 7 machine: for example, Windows shares weren't accessible from any workstation although ping worked fine.

After many hours of tries, I resolved by changing hostname of the machine of the shared printer.

Now everything works and I can print correctly from every other computer of the network.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `echo` instead of `print` to write to the console.